# Creating a custom data model for Qt SCXML

Tags: qt, scxml

I'm using Qt with an [SCXML state machine](https://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/). I want to use the native [Qt SCXML](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qtscxml-index.html) interpreter via [`QScxmlStateMachine`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qscxmlstatemachine.html). However, Qt only supports Null, EcmaScript, and C++ data models for SCXML. My state machine has a custom data model.

I would like to subclass [`QScxmlDataModel`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qscxmldatamodel.html) to support my state machine. I can see how implementing the `setup()`, `hasScxmlProperty()`, `setScxmlProperty()`, and `scxmlProperty()` functions would allow setting/getting values from the data model.

However, I don't see how to make it so that [expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/#Expressions) and other model-specific items—such as with `<transition cond="...">` or `<script>...</script>`—will properly be evaluated in my custom data model.

How can I make a custom data model that knows how to do more than just get/set properties?

Comment: Phrogz, You need to override the various [evaluate](https://github.com/qtproject/qtscxml/blob/5.7/src/scxml/qscxmldatamodel.h#L79) functions.

Comment: I do strongly wonder why those functions are being explicitly excluded from documentation.

Comment: Phrogz, my guess is that the API is not final. I posted it as answer.

Comment: Is this for sharing states between servers?

Comment: @nurettin Nope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to override the various evaluate functions of the `QScxmlDataModel` :

```
virtual QString evaluateToString(QScxmlExecutableContent::EvaluatorId id, bool *ok) = 0;
virtual bool evaluateToBool(QScxmlExecutableContent::EvaluatorId id, bool *ok) = 0;
virtual QVariant evaluateToVariant(QScxmlExecutableContent::EvaluatorId id, bool *ok) = 0;
virtual void evaluateToVoid(QScxmlExecutableContent::EvaluatorId id, bool *ok) = 0;
virtual void evaluateAssignment(QScxmlExecutableContent::EvaluatorId id, bool *ok) = 0;
virtual void evaluateInitialization(QScxmlExecutableContent::EvaluatorId id, bool *ok) = 0;
virtual bool evaluateForeach(QScxmlExecutableContent::EvaluatorId id, bool *ok, ForeachLoopBody *body) = 0;
```

They have all been excluded from the documentation, but you can see them [here](https://github.com/qtproject/qtscxml/blob/5.7/src/scxml/qscxmldatamodel.h#L78).

My guess the reason for this is that Qt SCXML module is released as [Technology Preview](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qtscxml-index.html) and the API might change in the future.

Comment: They are now [included](https://github.com/qt/qtscxml/blob/5.11/src/scxml/qscxmldatamodel.h#L78) in the documentation